# Dropdown animation not working

Tags: css, navbar, dropdown

I have this button on my navbar for mobiles;
[button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stnC6.png)

and i'd like to give the drop a animation when clicked, just like css ease, but cant get it to work
Tried putting it into @media, on related classes, and none of them worked.

```
.navbar .icon{
    display: none;
      position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navbar a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {display: none;}
 .dropdown .dropbtn {display:none;}
  .navbar a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block; 
     -webkit-transition: width 2s;

  }
}
```

fiddle for full code, except images; https://jsfiddle.net/1cy90aqb/ (resize window to show the button)
Thanks in advance

Comment: Declare transition to the navbar. You can read here how to do that corect: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-property

Answer (score 0):

Transitions do not work well while changing the `display` property of an element.
**Instead of using display,You could use the `visibility` property to add a transition to the element.**

```
.dropdown-content {

  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;

  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}




.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-content {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**Here's an updated jsFiddle of your code: https://jsfiddle.net/6mga5wzf/**

*change the transition time to see the effect.*

Hope that helps!